# Property of one class is another class, and vice-versa

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm programming a board game in C# where the two most important classes are `Piece` and `Square`. Typically every instance of `Piece` has a `Square` (as a property) and every instance of `Square` may have a `Piece` (also as a property) or may be empty.

I placed code in the set methods of `Square.Piece` and `Piece.Square` to ensure that this relationship was maintained (e.g. when a piece is moved from one square to another) and to avoid the obvious danger of the linked properties calling each other's set methods in an endless loop.

But when a `piece` is removed from the board and its `square` set to 'null' I seem to have too many if statements to avoid null exceptions and what seemed a very simple pattern conceptually becomes far too complex and error-prone in practice.

I'm wondering whether my whole approach is wrong. Should a `piece` have a `square` as a property when `Square` also has `Piece` as a property? Have I in fact started coding an anti-pattern? A `Piece`'s `Square` may be null on creation, and a `Square`'s `Piece` is frequently null (representing empty). Should I use another way to represent empty Squares and Pieces which are not on the board?

I'm assuming there are preferred, robust solutions to the more general case of when one class is linked to another in a two-way relationship such as this.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is square    element of board? and Piece the one that will be moved on board? if yes  Then I   think that you do not need Square property as Piece member. This additional information will not provide you useful extra information

Comment: So far there is no class 'Board'. I've just used a 2-dimentional array of Squares... Square[,] Board = Square[x,y].

But I'm thinking I should now have class Board, as although it will only every have one instance, all the higher-level methods like move(piece, originalSquare....) etc that SJuan76 suggested below, should presumably, properly, belong to Board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an higher level abstraction, with methods like

- `move(piece, originalSquare, destinationSqueare)`
- `place(piece, square)`
- `remove(piece)`
- `promote(originalPiece, finalPiece)`
- ...

these methods will use your basic methods from `Piece` and `Square`, and will be the ones used by your main logic

Comment: Many thanks. I'd wondered if this might be the way to go - but wanted confirmation from more experienced programmers before I made such a significant change.

So code methods such as you suggest, and therefore remove the linking code from the properties of Piece and Square.

Comment: +1 this approach. Re: problems with null, look at the NullObject pattern, e.g., define Piece.Empty, Square.OffBoard objects that have some appropriate behavior, to use instead of null values.

Comment: Thanks. I've done this. Implementing these null objects as static public fields of their own type within their parent class seems to work well. I had assumed this would would generate some recursion-related error. But now, for example, the first lines of Piece reads: `class Piece 
{
public static Piece none = new Piece("no piece");
....
`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're overthinking the process of removing a `Piece` from the `Board`.

The game is going to be centered on the `Board` class. Once you remove a `Piece` from the `Board`, that piece is gone; you're not going to do anything with it anymore. You won't be calling any of its methods or anything. That object is now dead -- unreachable. So there's not actually any reason to change the `Piece`'s state to null out its `Board` reference.

This is indeed a very common pattern, and the usual practice is to just let it go. Once nobody references the `Piece` anymore, you're done; it no longer *matters* that the `Piece` still happens to reference the `Board`. Let it keep its reference; it won't cause any harm (since nobody will be doing anything with that `Piece` anymore), and it'll be garbage collected soon anyway.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I don't just encounter problems when I remove a Piece, but when I move a Piece from one Square to another, leaving the original Square.Piece 'null'. I think I've created a classic Circular dependency, and discovered from scratch just how error-prone such a structure is.